# How to vibrate "while" a single listview item is pressed - android?

Tags: android, listview, vibration

I've got a listview with just two elements.

You press one of them, it should vibrate for 1000 milliseconds and stop.

Press the other one, and WHILE your finger is down pressing it, it should be vibrating.

Again, You click first item, it vibrates for 1000 milliseconds ... and while you TOUCH AND HOLD the second item, it should be vibrating until you remove your finger.

Below I've got the code for the same:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Vibrator x = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                x.vibrate(1000);
                break;
            case 1: break;// Need To vibrate while pressed here
            }

        }

    });

    listview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Vibrator x = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                x.vibrate(5000);
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Vibrator xa = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                xa.cancel();
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

So, I have two listeners

In the first one (OnItemClick) ..

If the 1st button is pressed, I vibrate for 1 sec.

If I have only this function, it works great ( for the first button)

In the second listener, I take the motionevent since I need to know when the user has pressed down and back up..

However, It seems that the second listener overrides the first one.

The setOnItemListener doesn't work at all, when I have both these listeners present in my OnCreate().

On their own, each function does exactly what I want it to. But I need to combine the two of them.

I need to setOnTouchListener inside the "Case:1" of the OnItemListener ...

So that when first item is clicked it vibrates for 1 sec... and when 2nd item is clicked, it vibrates as long as the item is pressed (while in focused state)

Any idea how to combine these two ?

(The above code works perfectly well, I just need to put the Touch Listener inside the OnItemClick(), but it gives an error...  Please feel free to copy paste , I just need to figure out how exactly to place the functions...)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Move your `OnTouchListener` to the `View` inflated by the `ListAdapter` for `View`s with `position > 0`.

This way should fix:

1. `OnItemClickListener` should still work.
2. It vibrates only when touching the 1.. items.